# ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; at line 1

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, list

ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

This error keeps occurring as I try to bring web-scraped data from a list into a database on mysql. I've no idea how to remedy, i've tried adding '' around string inputs but nothing seems to be working.

```
for container in listings:
    #extracting price
    price = container.div.div.strong.text
    price = price.strip('AMV: €')
    price = price.strip('Reserve: €')
    price = price.replace(',', "")
    price = int(price)
    p_list.append(price)

    #location
    location = container.div.find("a", {"class":"PropertyInformationCommonStyles__addressCopy-- 
    link"}).text
    n_list.append("'"+location+"'")
    #house type
    house = container.div.find("div", {"class":"QuickPropertyDetails__propertyType"}).text
    h_list.append("'"+house+"'")
    #number of bathrooms
    bath_num = container.div.find("div", {"class":"QuickPropertyDetails__iconCopy-- 
    WithBorder"}).text
    #makes str and int
    bath_num = int(bath_num)
    ba_list.append(bath_num)
        #number of bedrooms
    bed_num = container.div.find("div", {"class":"QuickPropertyDetails__iconCopy"}).text
    bed_num = int(bed_num)
    be_list.append(bed_num)
    #makes str and int
    all_var.append((price, location, house, bath_num, bed_num))
    #connecting to database     
import mysql.connector

d_b = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "MY_ACCOUNT", passwd = "MY_PASSWORD", database 
= "daftdatabase",)
print(d_b)
mycursor = d_b.cursor()
#create database
#mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE daftdatabase")
#create table
#mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE DaftTable(price Integer(10), location VARCHAR(50), type VARCHAR(20), bedrooms INTEGER(2),  bathrooms INTEGER(2))")
show_table = mycursor.execute("SHOW TABLE")

for var in all_var:
data = mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO DaftTable(price, location, type, bathrooms, bedrooms) 
VALUES"+var)
```

Genuinely no idea what to do so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: just a note: not a great idea to share login credentials here. Suggest editing to something generic, ie: user='foo', passwd='bar'

Comment: You are not inserting quotes properly starting on your VARCHAR line... You have to remember that python see's those quotes as well.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim in the create table line?

Comment: @AdrianKenneally actually looking at it again... basically everything below the line 'mycursor = d_b.cursor()' is a syntax error for python. You need to place it in a variable and then execute the variable on the db cursor

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim Could you elaborate on this please? place which in a variable, as in all the following lines of code? sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct MySQL statement is [`SHOW TABLES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-tables.html) (notice the plural form), not `SHOW TABLE`.

Comment: I changed this then an error about the tuples have to be strings after I changed them to strings this error occured: InternalError: Unread result found

Comment: that's a totally different error, the one in this question being solved. You should accept my answer as the correct one and post a new question with your new error.